# Why does my use of javascript's reduce function return "undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

**1)** I've got an array of objects, called employees.

**2)** I'm trying to find the highest paid employee in the array.

**3)** I'm using Javascript's reduce function (inside function findHighestPaid) to do so.

**4)** Running findHighestPaid(employees) returns "undefined" when I expected it to return the object that has property name: Abelard.

**Here's my code.**

```
const employees = [
  {
    name: "Aziz",
    salary: 17050,
  },
  {
    name: "Angela",
    salary: 17060,
  },
  {
    name: "Abelard",
    salary: 17070,
  },
];

function findHighestPaid(arrayOfObjects) {
  let myObject = {
    name: "pretendEmployee",
    salary: 17040,
  };

  arrayOfObjects.reduce(myFunction, myObject);

  function myFunction(acc, item) {
    let personSalary = item.salary;
    let accSalary = acc.salary;
    if (Math.sign(personSalary - accSalary) > 0) {
      console.log(`returning object for ${item.name}`);
      return item;
    } else {
      console.log(`returning object for ${acc.name}`);
      return acc;
    }
  } // end myFunction
}
```

When I run findHighestPaid(employees) and look in console I see :

returning object for Aziz    // (as I expected)

returning object for Angela  // (as I expected)

returning object for Abelard // (as I expected)

undefined                    // (**oh oh!!!**)

**Why does the reduce function return "undefined"?**

Comment: Because you ignore the return value of "reduce", and "findHighestPaid" doesn't return anything. Unrelated, but reasonable indentation makes code much easier to read.

Comment: I think I'll just give up coding now . Thank you so much!

Comment: by the way, thank you also for the advice on indents. my excuse is that it's past my bedtime where i am! best wishes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `undefined` that's being printed at the end is the return value of `findHighestPaid()` function that you run.

since you're not returning anything it's returning `undefined`.
if your goal is to see the return value of `reduce()` add a return statement to the function like this:

```js
const employees = [
  {
    name: "Aziz",
    salary: 17050,
  },
  {
    name: "Angela",
    salary: 17060,
  },
  {
    name: "Abelard",
    salary: 17070,
  },
];

function findHighestPaid(arrayOfObjects) {
  let myObject = {
    name: "pretendEmployee",
    salary: 17040,
  };

  return arrayOfObjects.reduce(myFunction, myObject);

  function myFunction(acc, item) {
    let personSalary = item.salary;
    let accSalary = acc.salary;
    if (Math.sign(personSalary - accSalary) > 0) {
      console.log(`returning object for ${item.name}`);
      return item;
    } else {
      console.log(`returning object for ${acc.name}`);
      return acc;
    }
  } // end myFunction
}

console.log(findHighestPaid(employees));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working perfectly although you don't need `Math.sign` at all, just `return` the result:

```js
const employees = [
  {
    name: "Aziz",
    salary: 17050,
  },
  {
    name: "Angela",
    salary: 17080,
  },
  {
    name: "Abelard",
    salary: 17070,
  },
];

function findHighestPaid(arrayOfObjects) {
  let myObject = {
    name: "pretendEmployee",
    salary: 17040,
  };

  return arrayOfObjects.reduce(myFunction, myObject);

  function myFunction(acc, item) {
    let personSalary = item.salary;
    let accSalary = acc.salary;
    if (personSalary - accSalary > 0) {
      console.log(`returning object for ${item.name}`);
      return item;
    } else {
      console.log(`returning object for ${acc.name}`);
      return acc;
    }
  } // end myFunction
}

console.log('Highest paid', findHighestPaid(employees));
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to put it like this

```
function findHighestPaid(arrayOfObjects) {
    return arrayOfObjects.reduce((prev, curr) => {
        if(!prev) {
            return curr;
        }

        return curr.salary > prev.salary ? curr : prev;    
    }, null);
}

const highestPaidEmployee = findHighestPaid(employees);
```